# script to modify local group policy

Tags: windows

After installed WSUS on win server 2008, I need to create a script (to execute) on windows clients to automatically modify some settings, ie:

```
Group Policy Object Editor  -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update
```

is there a comfortable way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean, aside from using actual Group Policy on a domain level?  That's the easiest way.

If you don't have AD, or can't use that for some reason, there are registry keys you can import to make those changes.  (I used to use them all the time on XP before we had AD.)  Look for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate` and subkeys.  (There's a complete reference [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).)

The absolute easiest thing to do would be to set the keys via your GUI, delete the SusclientID and PingID keys (otherwise, only one machine will receive updates), export the keys, and use a script to run a `regmerge /s filename.reg` on the clients to import them.